# OleDbDataReader to ArrayList in C#

Tags: c#, arraylist, datareader, .net, oledbdatareader

How to iterate through `OleDbDataReader` and put its elements into `ArrayList`?

Here is my code:

```
// ...

ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

while(myReader.Read())
{
    foreach(string s in myReader) // I got an Exception here
    {
        list.Add(s);
    }
}

// ...

Label lbl = new Label();
lbl.Text = list[i] as string;
```

and here is the Exception:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal' to type 'System.String'.
```

Comment: I don't get it. What are you trying to do? Put strings from all available columns into a list, regardless of the column name or type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
while (myReader.Read())
{
  list.Add(myReader.GetString(0));
}
```

Comment: I am not sure why I got this error: `Cannot convert type 'char' to 'string'`

Comment: edit your question with your new code, without seeing it is impossible to answer!

Comment: This answer is apparently wrong. `GetString` returns a string, and `foreach` in a string is looping through the characters of the string.

Comment: If you donnt know the datatype , you could use  myReader.GetValue(0) + ""